# Using predicates in custom implemented data structures

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, predicate

I have a cusom implemented `Heap` for priority queue application

```
class Heap {
   SomeCutsomClass elements[100];
   ....
   ....
};
```

Now I need to support two different comparison operation between the `keys` of the heap and I want to implement it using c++ predicates

```
struct less1
{
   bool operator()(const SomeCutsomClass& c1, const SomeCutsomClass& c1)
   {
    //specific implementation
   }
};

struct less2
{
   bool operator()(const SomeCutsomClass& c1, const SomeCutsomClass& c1)
   {
    //specific implementation
   }
};
```

Ideally I should be able to pass the predicates somehow in the constructor of `Heap`

I am not able to visualize how to achieve this.
It is not that I want to use only predicates.Since I cant overload same operator twice in `SomeCutsomClass` , I am trying to use predicates.
I tried looking up STL source code of some well known data structures like `std::sort` etc , but they look complicated to me.

Comment: Both your less 1 and less 2 struct are functors. You can assign instances of such functor, and any function with a corresponding signature, to a variable of type std::function<bool(const SomeCutsomClass&, const SomeCutsomClass&)> to store the function and use it later.

Comment: Typically a class like your `Heap` (or `std::set`) would take a (stateless) comparison fuciton-object by type so that at runtime your `Heap<less1>` would have `less1::operator()` inlined into itself. (You want your `operator()`s to be `const` (that's `const` after the argument list). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: If you want to deviate a bit from the STL approach, you could use std::function<bool (const SomeCutsomClass&,SomeCutsomClass&)> to pass in a predicate. You can then either pass predicates with this signature (or lambas with captures with this signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example containing both an example of std::less use and custom predicates as functions (lambdas).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>

// Make heap a class template
// this allows you to specialize easily for any class
// I added the STL like third template parameter as example
// type_t is the type to store in the heap
// N is the size of the heap
template<typename type_t, std::size_t N, class Compare = std::less<type_t>>
class Heap
{
public:
    using pred_t = std::function<bool(const type_t&, const type_t&)>;

    Heap() :
        m_predicate{ Compare() }
    {
    }

    explicit Heap(pred_t predicate) :
        m_predicate{ predicate }
    {
    }

    bool compare(const int a, const int b)
    {
        return m_predicate(a, b);
    }

private:
    std::array<type_t, N> m_elements;
    pred_t m_predicate;
};

struct SomeCustomClass
{
    // all you need to make SomeCustomClass usable in Heap
    // if it uses std::less as third template parameter 
    // is to provide this compare overload
    bool operator<(const SomeCustomClass& other) const
    {
        return m_value < other.m_value;
    }

    int m_value{};
};

int main()
{
    // this heap will use std::less
    Heap<int, 100> less_heap;
    assert(less_heap.compare(1, 2));

    // create a lambda predicate 
    auto pred = [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs)
    {
        return lhs > rhs;
    };

    // this heap will use custom predciate
    Heap<int, 100> greater_heap(pred);
    assert(greater_heap.compare(2,1));

    //
    Heap<SomeCustomClass, 10> custom_heap;

    return 0;
}
```